# why do I get 'wsimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I entered

`C:\>wsimport -keep http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL`

at command prompt to create web services client and I got :

```
'wsimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What could the problem be? JDK path is set correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Go to this folder "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin" or something like this and then try. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your path is pointing somewhere else than you expect. Off the top of my head I can think of two things:

1. The PATH might point to a JRE and not a JDK. The `wsimport` tool is in the JDK, not the JRE.
2. Are you testing the path by running `java.exe` directly?... and it works! Note that `java.exe` doesn't necessary need to be specified in the PATH, [there is one `java.exe` in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES) and that gets picked up.

> What could the problem be? JDK path is set correctly.

I would double check that.

If you have multiple versions of Java installed, a PATH setting might pick up the wrong version of your files. In that case go in the `bin` folder of the JDK you want to use and run `wsimport` from there. If you just have one version installed then check your PATH because it's definitely a PATH issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the environment variable. Under system variable choose "PATH" and edit it.
In the new dialog box **append** path till bin folder of jdk. It MUST work.